# BASH SCRIPT: Echo to file is transfered to remote host

Tags: bash, debian, ssh, scp, echo

I am writing a bash script in order to perform
some automatic backups to a remote storage server.
The batch script will be run with cron jobs however I'm testing it before.
See script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
BACKUPS_PATH='/home/web/xxx/yyy/pb_data/backups'
cd $BACKUPS_PATH
CURRENT_DIRECTORY=$(pwd)
echo "Current directory is: ${CURRENT_DIRECTORY}"
LATEST_BACKUP=$(ls -Art | tail -n 1)
echo "Latest backup file is: ${LATEST_BACKUP}"
FILE_PATH="${BACKUPS_PATH}/${LATEST_BACKUP}"
echo "Latest backup entire path is: ${FILE_PATH}"
DATE=$(date)
echo "Datetime: ${DATE}"
echo "Script has run at ${DATE}" > auto_backup.log
scp -P 23 $FILE_PATH xxx@yyy:/home/backups
```

Everything works correctly except for the fact that when I'm trying to echo the date to auto_backup.log, the file does not get created locally, instead I can find it in the remote host where the backup files get transfered instead.
I don't understand this behaviour, since the line is running before the scp connection is even established.
Does anyone know why this happens and how should it be fixed?

Comment: Please run your script through https://www.shellcheck.net/, you have quite a few bad practices there.

Comment: @terdon Thank you sir, I did not know about the mentioned website, also to be honest I did not think that there would be bad practices in less than 20 lines but it seems like there are.

Comment: You're welcome. That site is a great tool. One thing it doesn't mention is that it is also a bad idea to use CAPS for your own variables. Since, [by convention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/1081936), global environment variables are capitalized, it is bad practice to also use caps for your own, local variables because this can lead to naming collisions and hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reviewing the question I realized it's because I CD in the backup directory path, that's where the log gets created and becomes the latest file to transfer.
This is now solved